# YouTube.Search.list ReferenceError

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, youtube-data-api

YouTube.Search.list in Google Apps Scripts shows this error: ReferenceError: "YouTube" is not defined (line 22).

Dashboard shows that the request went through each time I ran the code. Youtube Data API is enabled in Apps Script and Dev Console.

Any help appreciated on why I'm getting this error.

```
/*
  YouTube RSS Feeds
  Written by @user1535152 http://stackoverflow.com/q/30486682/512127
  Based on http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-rss-feed/28149/  
*/

function doGet(e) {

  var title  = ("Youtube RSS Feed for " + e.parameter.search),
      timez  = Session.getScriptTimeZone(),
      search = encodeURIComponent(e.parameter.search),
      link   = ("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search),
      self   = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl() + "?" + search;

  var rss='<?xml version="1.0"?>';
  rss+='<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">';
  rss+='<channel><title>'+title+'</title>';
  rss+='<link>'+link+'</link>';
  rss+='<atom:link href="'+self+'" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />';
  rss+='<description>' + title + ' updated on ' + new Date() + '.</description>';

  var results = YouTube.Search.list('id, snippet', {
    q: search,
    maxResults: 50,
    order: 'date'
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++){
    var item = results.items[i];
    rss += "<item>";
    rss += "<title>" + item.snippet.title + "</title>";
    rss += "<link>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + item.id.videoId + "</link>";
    rss += "<description>" + item.snippet.description + "</description>";
    rss += "<pubDate>" + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(item.snippet.publishedAt), timez, "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z") + "</pubDate>";
    rss += "<guid>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + item.id.videoId + "</guid>";
    rss += "</item>";
  }

  rss+="</channel></rss>";

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(rss).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.RSS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it was found that "Youtube Data API is enabled in Apps Script and Dev Console.". But an error of `ReferenceError: "YouTube" is not defined` occurs, when the script is run. So please confirm a following setting.

In order to use `YouTube.Search.list()`, it requires not only enabling API at API console, but also enabling at Advanced Google Services. I confirmed that when `YouTube Data API` is OFF at Advanced Google Services, the same error occurs. In order to enable `YouTube Data API` at Advanced Google Services, please confirm as follows.

1. Open script editor that there is the script.
2. Click Resources -> Advanced Google Services.
3. Turn on `YouTube Data API`.
4. Click OK.

If `YouTube Data API` is "off", please turn on by clicking. After this, please try to run, again.

If this is not useful for you, I'm sorry.